# Run php at cloud9 and connent mysql fail -- Unknown database 'world'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
<?php
$mysql_host='localhost:3306';
$mysql_user='root';
$mysql_password='';
$mysql_db='world';
$con= mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_db)
      or die("Error ".mysqli_error($con));
?>
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

> Warning: 
>   mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'world' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-world.php

[image: Screenshot1]

I run the php at cloud9

I had edit the **privileges** and the **DB:world actually exist**

[image: Screenshot 2]

but why always query DB"world" fail, the db actually exist!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a workspace in c9 and I can not replicate the issue using the exact same code and making a database using phpmyadmin, did you install phpmyadmin using phpmyadmin-ctl install?
Also are you connecting to phpmyadmin over yourid.c9users.io/phpmyadmin
If you did all of the following I would request support from c9 or recreate your workspace (probably easier).